# Keycloak with NSIS

Tags: windows, windows-installer, keycloak, nsis

I'm making a NSIS file for windows installer.
I have the need to install keycloak 15.1.1 as a service on Windows, and add first admin user (for example in command line) and restart the server after that because after adding a user keycloak must be restart, after import a realm in an existing file on the file system.

For the moment I tried that but nothing work correctly without service and only launching the bin/standalone.bat of keycloak, more over the process open a windows terminal and continue to execute.

Bellow my code:

```
start_keycloak_service:
    ; Launch Keycloak service
    ;DetailPrint "Starting Keycloak service"
    MessageBox mb_ok "Starting Keycloak server"
    ;StrCpy $KeycloakStandaloneBatPath "$INSTDIR\${CS_KEYCLOAK_VERSION}\bin\standalone.bat"
    ExecShell "open" "${KeycloakStandaloneBatPath} -Djboss.http.port=3001" SW_HIDE
    Sleep 10000
    
    ; Add keycloak admin
    StrCpy $KeycloakAdminUser "admin"
    StrCpy $KeycloakAdminPassword "admin"
    StrCpy $KeycloakKcAddUserKeycloakBatPath "$INSTDIR\${CS_KEYCLOAK_VERSION}\bin\add-user-keycloak.bat"
    StrCpy $0 "$KeycloakKcAddUserKeycloakBatPath -u $KeycloakAdminUser -p $KeycloakAdminPassword"
    MessageBox mb_ok "$0"
    MessageBox mb_ok "keycloak admin create"
    StrCpy $KeycloakKcAdmBinPath "$INSTDIR\${CS_KEYCLOAK_VERSION}\bin\kcadm.bat"

    ; crimson realm file to import path
    StrCpy $RealmImportFile "$INSTDIR\Packages\keycloak.15.1.1.json"
    DetailPrint "Import crimson realm ${RealmImportFile}"

    ; realm import command with kcadm.sh
    StrCpy $0 "$KeycloakKcAdmBinPath config credentials --server http://localhost:3001/auth --realm master --user $KeycloakAdminUser --password $KeycloakAdminPassword"
    StrCpy $1 "KeycloakKcAdmBinPath create realms -f $RealmImportFile"
    
    MessageBox mb_ok "$0"
    Exec '"$0"'
    MessageBox mb_ok "keycloak user authenticate"
    MessageBox mb_ok "$1"
    MessageBox mb_ok "Realm imported"
```

My need is to just create an admin user and import a new realm, but I tried by defining service.conf file and create a service, but the service make an error during the launch. Is for that I tried to only launch by .bat but nothing very usefull and success ...

Comment: What is the error during launch?

Comment: Your ExecShell is wrong, the quotes need to be `ExecShell  "open" '"${KeycloakStandaloneBatPath}" -Djboss.http.port=3001' SW_HIDE`

Comment: @Anders sorry it doesn't work properly, because I don't know why but the command launch me the keycloak as "svchost.exe (NetSvc -P) IPv6 unspecified 3001 TCP" and "svchost.exe (NetSvc -P) IPv4 unspecified 3001 TCP"  but unreachable on my web navigator on 3001 port ... and When I launch it with the direct command line like C:/keycloak/bin/standalone.bat -Djboss.http.port=3001, is create a process "java.exe loopback IPv4 3001 TCP" and this process is accessible in my navigator ... I don't know why the difference, make that with ExecShell keycloak is not correctly launch

Comment: ExecShell is pretty much the same as double-clicking a file in Explorer.

Comment: @Anders it seems not for me .... in my program